# Set NSString based on condition

Tags: objective-c

I am struggling with the best way to create a NSString object with alloc/init, and then set its contents based on a condition.

I try this:

```
        if (amount==@"current") { 
            NSString * suffix=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"contents1"];
        } else {
             NSString * suffix=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"contents2"];
        }
```

however if I try to use "suffix" anywhere, the compiler doesn't like it; claims it is undeclared.

However, since I want a simple inmutable string, I cannot set it before the "if" and then assign it during the "if" so I'm not sure how to approach this?

Comment: The variable is out of scope, Mister.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code fails because you are declaring the string variable within the branches of the `if/else`. This declaration is local to its curly-braces and does not exist outside of them. If you move the declaration outside the `if` statement, you can use the branches of the `if` to assign to this (shared) variable:

```
BOOL isCurrent = [amount isEqualToString:@"current"];
if (isCurrent) {
    suffix = @"contents1";
} else {
    suffix = @"contents2";
}
```

Conditional assignment is a good place to use the ternary operator `?:`. `P? X : Y` is similar to `if (P) X; else Y;`. Unlike `if`, which is a statement that relies on assignment and other side effects to affect its environment, `?:` is an expression that returns the value of the chosen branch. You can use `?:` to do what you want like so:

```
BOOL isCurrent = [amount isEqualToString:@"current"];
NSString *suffix = isCurrent? @"contents1" : @"contents2";
```

Comment: does this create an autoreleased "suffix" ? suppose you want to manage its memory via alloc/init rather than use autorelease? I tried this and it works: `suffix=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"contents1"];` inside each "if" and "else", and then i have a single `[suffix release]` later; is this healthy?

Comment: Strings like `@"foo"` are not reference-counted. They are static strings that persist throughout the application's lifetime. If you're not actually using a format, just a string, you can use `-initWithString:` to get an owning reference or `-stringWithString:` to get an autoreleased reference.

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring `NSString *suffix;` before you do the if/else statement:

```
NSString *suffix;
if ([amount isEqualToString:@"current"]) {
suffix = @"contents1";
} else {
suffix = @"contents2";
}
```

That should work. (Also, you can't use `==` for NSStrings).

Comment: To avoid future problems, I recommend starting with `NSString *suffix = nil;`.  And to clarify, `==` will evaluate pointer equality, not object equality.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. Should I change my answer?